# JavaScript function return object to be used where the function was called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have a function like the following, but the function calling this one return undefined, I don't know why.

```
$.fileReader_g = function(file){
        var reader  = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onloadend = function(){
                return {
                        result:     reader.result, 
                        size:       file.size, 
                        name:       file.name
                }
            }

        if (file){
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
                console.log('Upload Failed');
        }
    }
```

The above is called by the following.

```
$(document).on('change', '.album_art_select', function(){
        var cow = $.fileReader_g($(this)[0].files[0]);
        console.log(cow);
    });
```

Where am I missing this?

Comment: You did not `return` anything from inside the `$.fileReader_g` function. The function does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define two functions.

One you assign to `$.fileReader_g`. It does not have a `return` statement and will always return `undefined`.

The other you assign to `reader.onloadend`. It does have a `return` statement, but nothing is going to pay any attention to it.

See also [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).